# php file isn't recognising my sqlite3 db mydb.sq3

Tags: php, sqlite, xampp

I'm running xampp.

I created a basic db call mydb.sq3 and a basic table called panels. That all seems to work fine because when I call `SELECT * FROM panels;` from the command line it is all good. But there is an error that keeps getting thrown when i run my php file:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function query() in > C:\xampp\htdocs\example\myphp.php on line 10

```
<?php
    $db = new SQLite3('mydb.sq3');
    $result = $db-->query('SELECT * FROM panels');
    while ($row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
    {
          echo $row['firstname'] . ': $' . $row['surname'] . '<br/>';
    }
   unset($db);
?>
```

Cheers

Comment: one to many dashes ---------

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in line 3

Use this-

```
$result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM panels');
```

Instead of this -

```
$result = $db-->query('SELECT * FROM panels');
```

Simple typo error you used '--' instead of '-' Enjoy :)